# Telnet Chat in python - User name and password

Tags: python, sockets, telnet

I've been messing around with telnet in python and came across some well designed code but the problem I have is I would love to be able to see who logs in by giving the a user name and password. I've done research on telnet and the python modules that go with it but for the life of me I cant figure it out. If someone could show an example that would be great.

Here is my code:

```
import socket, threading

HOST = '192.168.177.141'
PORT = 51234 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(4)
clients = [] #list of clients connected
lock = threading.Lock()


class chatServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, (socket,address)):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.address= address

    def run(self):
        lock.acquire()
        clients.append(self)
        lock.release()
        print '%s:%s connected.' % self.address
        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            for c in clients:
                c.socket.send(data)
        self.socket.close()
        print '%s:%s disconnected.' % self.address
        lock.acquire()
        clients.remove(self)
        lock.release()

while True: 

    chatServer(s.accept()).start()
```

Comment: Can you use `select`?

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_A4_2.pdf is a good read, you should really read this cover to cover

Comment: `select` is a utility found on Linux and BSD systems, not sure about windows, you give is 3 lists and optionally a timeout, if any of the sockets or files in the lists are ready to do something it returns with them in the list (or with empty lists if it timed-out) the lists are read write and "exception" respectively, so you'd put all your clients on the read list, this function would return with a list of clients that sent you data, it's very useuful

Comment: It may be on Windows systems BTW, I wouldn't know. http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Comment: not sure how i could add that into this code im completly new to networking inside of python

Comment: `readyToRead, readyToWrite, exceptions = select(clientList,[],clientList,0.5);` then `readyToRead` contains the things from `clientList` that have data for you to read :)

Comment: can you show me in a full script?

Comment: Yes, I'll write one when I've gotten dressed and stuff, about an hour, until then READ THAT PDF. networking makes a lot more sense when you know what's going on.

Comment: i know networking im in cisco 4 as a senior in high school ready to take my ccna test

Comment: Great you can configure routers and understand how packets are sent, but you clearly don't know how the OS __presents__ sockets, which is important! You ought to have seen the 7 layer network model, EVERYTHING below the Transport level is something you don't need to know about for network programming, an inkling doesn't hurt but that's the OS's and hardware's job. So you can know a lot about the ones below transport (which you do) but above.... this is where that guide is important.

Comment: I'm reading this pdf its quite interesting. Yep know that model.

Comment: Good boy.       [padding]

Comment: i thought you said you could give me an example?

Comment: Hey, yeah have you been reading too?

Comment: yes i have been reading